# Separate a file in paragraphs

Tags: python, split, paragraphs

I have a file like this:

```
cluster number 1

1

2

3

cluster number 2

1

2

3

cluster number x

1

2

3
```

I want to split this file in paragraph of cluster numbers, like this

```
cluster number 1

1

2

3
```

I try to search for an answer but I can't handle it.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd append to Barmars language question, and from what file format?

Comment: To add to both: What have you tried so far?

Comment: In python. Its a text file. I tried to split for cluster word, but it doesn't work.

Comment: use regular expression

Comment: Im new in python, can you help me with regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

user regular expression

```
import re
input_text = "..."
r = re.findall(r"(cluster number (\d+)\n\n(\d+)\n\n(\d+)\n\n(\d+))", input_text)
print r
```

this code return below list

```
[('cluster number 1\n\n1\n\n2\n\n3', '1', '1', '2', '3'),
 ('cluster number 2\n\n1\n\n2\n\n3', '2', '1', '2', '3')]
```

you can also see the detail explanation from [here](http://regex101.com/r/gW1qG1)

Answer (score 0):

As recommended, you should use regular expressions. Perhaps the re.split function would be suitable here:

```
>>> l = re.split('cluster number (?:\d+)', x)[1:]
>>> [a.split() for a in l]
[['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3'], ...]
```